How to define a variable in @each block (according to other variable name)?
I want to import all scss variables into js file. source
$theme-colors: (
  'someColor': #000,
  'anotherColor': #FFF,
);

:export {
  @each $key, $value in $theme-colors {
    #{unquote($key)}: $value;
  }
}

But this way I have to use map.get in scss files with these scss variables.
I would prefer to define normal scss variables and use them. So I tried the following:
$colors: (
  red: "red"
);

@each $key, $value in $colors {
  $key: $value;
}

I want to be able to define a scss variable $red: "red";, but it failed.
Or is there any way to destructure $colors?

Users occasionally want to use interpolation to define a variable name based on another variable. Sass doesn’t allow this, because it makes it much harder to tell at a glance which variables are defined where. What you can do, though, is define a map from names to values that you can then access using variables. scss document


I don't think you can define variables in @each like that. Why do you want to do it?

You can use map-get($colors, red) for example. Don't see why you would make new variables from something you can get from map.

@MilosStojanovic I want to be able to :export all variables to the js file example. However, this writing method makes normal scss variables unusable. The ordinary scss variable is $red: "red", which does not use scss map $colors.

You can map them to CSS variables and use those.

You pretty much answered your own question by quoting the excerpt from the official documentation; you cannot create SASS variables by interpolation; this is a known limitation.
This leaves you with two approaches:

The one you have posted: use a map to hold related variables; access the map via map.get wherever you need to reference the variable; loop over the map in your :export

Ditch the map and define the variables flat: you can still group related variables by location (sections within one file or split into separate files). Accessing the variables is simpler; :export can't use a loop and must list all exported variables. I usually go with the second approach even in larger projects because in my book the simplicity trumps the conciseness of the :export-loop


// colors.scss

$dark-red: #782112;
$light-red: #981257;
$lightest-red: #826712;
$darkest-blue: #458229;
$dark-blue: #648274;
$light-blue: #674820;

:export {
  darkRed: #{$dark-red};
  lightRed: #{$light-red};
  lightestRed: #{$lightest-red};
  darkestBlue: #{$darkest-blue};
  darkBlue: #{$dark-blue};
  lightBlue: #{$light-blue};
}


This way the same code needs to be written twice. However, there seems to be no better way unless scss supports it.
